# How to draw Multi color line graph in Java script on range basis?

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph

[image]HI All i want to draw a line graph for data which is varying with time. I need to have multiple colors in this graph for the different range of values.
Could you please help me in it

Comment: You can use google charts. Try https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart

Comment: you could use syncfusion charts..http://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web/

Comment: Thanks but all these charts have multiple lines with different colors none of them shows me an option which gives  single line with multi color segments

Answer (score 0):

I just have the same problem and I'm planning to use AmCharts :http://www.amcharts.com/javascript-charts/ See the demos : http://www.amcharts.com/demos/

Plus it hase a wp plugin... just sayin' :)